# PF firewall on FreeBSD for allowing SSH and OpenVPN Traffic

Tags: firewall, openvpn, freebsd, pf

I'm trying to create a simple ansible template for the packet filter on FreeBSD 11.1-RELEASE. I have `vtnet0` (public), `vtnet1` (private, 10.10 address) and `tun0` (openvpn, fully working/tested from a client to nodes on my network).

My rc.conf looks like the following:

```
hostname="bastion"
sshd_enable="YES"
static_routes="linklocal"
ifconfig_vtnet0="DHCP"
ifconfig_vtnet0_ipv6="inet6 accept_rtadv"
ipv6_activate_all_interfaces="YES"
rtsold_enable="YES"
rtsold_flags="-aF"
ifconfig_vtnet1="inet 10.10.6.20 netmask 255.255.255.0"
gateway_enable="YES"
openvpn_enable="YES"
pf_enable="YES"
```

My cloud provider gives me ipv4/ipv6 public addresses via DHCP.

I've looked at the FreeBSD docs and other ansible playbooks and came up with this basic pf.conf:

```
block all
set skip on lo0
set skip on tun0
pass out all keep state
tcp_services = "{ ssh }"
udp_services = "{ openvpn }"
pass in proto tcp to any port $tcp_services keep state
pass in proto udp to any port $udp_services keep state
```

However with this configuration, I block all ssh and openvpn access and have to login to my box via the VM web console.

My goal is for this box to only allow in openvpn (udp) and ssh from the public interface, allow all traffic over the vpn (tun0) and all traffic from internal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting up `pf` may be a bit of a hassle. You need to understand that `pf` treats all interfaces absolutely equally and there is no concept of packets originating on the box itself as there is in `iptables` -- `OUTPUT` chain. I would start with something along these lines and build on that:

```
# allow all from host itself
pass out inet all keep state
pass out inet6 all keep state
# allow all from private
pass in quick on vtnet1 inet from any to any keep state
# openvpn
pass in quick proto udp to vtnet0 port openvpn keep state
pass in quick on tun0 inet from any to any keep state
# ssh
pass in quick proto tcp to vtnet0 port ssh flags S/SA keep state
```

Warning: Don't use standard openvpn and ssh ports.

Comment: I put in an edit to have the inet6 rules on the public services (the private interface only has an ipv4 address, so it was failing validation). However if I add `block all`, I lose all network connectivity. Without the block all, I can still run services on other ports. Does the rule order matter? Should blocking go at the end?

Comment: One more thing, I'm not married to pf. I'm a little confused by FreeBSD's three firewall options. I'm fine with using another option if it makes more sense in this situation.

Comment: The order matters: the last match wins. You have to keep `block all` at the top. Let's focus on making `ssh` work. Change my top three rules to: `pass from { self, vtnet1 } to any keep state` and replace bottom two with `pass in proto tcp to vtnet0 port ssh`. Also, is it a real gateway? If so, you need at the very top `nat on vtnet0 inet from vtnet1:network to any -> (vtnet0)`.

Comment: So I'm not using this box as a gateway (each box in the private network just has a static route back to it from the openvpn subnet). I put in another edit and this one seems to work perfectly. I only have two ports exposed on public, and everything private/openvpn(tun0) works correctly. What do you think?

Comment: I am not a big fan of `skip`s unless absolutely necessary. Check out the latest edit and let me know if it works like that.

Comment: A simple variant of this worked for me with macOS High Sierra, where I wanted to allow SSH to my local machine while connected with ExpressVPN. Thanks!

In my case my home iMac is behind a firewalling/NAT'ing router box; `en0` is my local ethernet and `utun7` is the OpenVPN TUN adapter used by ExpressVPN. 

```pass out inet all keep state; 
pass in quick on en0 inet from any to any keep state; 
pass in quick proto udp to en0 port openvpn keep state; pass in quick on utun7 inet from any to any keep state; pass in quick proto tcp to en0 port ssh flags S/SA keep state```